# Blackberry: (Java) Submit data to a webpage

Tags: java, blackberry

I have a working application which gets the GPS Long/Lat of from a BlackBerry device. I'm now trying to submit this to a webpage.

```
OpenURL( "http://website.net:80/track/Tracker/track?userid=1&longitude="+gps.getLongitude()+"&latitude="+gps.getLatitude() );
```

And the function

```
    public void OpenURL(String URL)
    {
        try{
            HttpConnection c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open( URL, Connector.READ,true);
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

This crashes the application without any error message, can anyone advise of why this may be? Do I need to set this off in its own thread. I was hoping to submit to the website every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately on BlackBerry you can't just give Connector a URL and expect it to work you need to append information after the URL to tell it which connection method to use.  Look at [this post on the BlackBerry forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/td-p/206242) and [this sample code](http://www.versatilemonkey.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/24/networking-helper-class/) showing you how to choose a connection method.